# 08001 Microsoft ODBC SQL Server Driver DBNETLIB SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc, pyodbc

I'm facing an issue while trying to connect to a SQL Server using pyodbc in Python. Here are the details of the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:\Chat GPT With SQL\test.py", line 23, in <module> conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str) pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')`

**Code Snippet:**

```
import urllib

import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI

# Replace these values with your actual database connection details
db_config = {
    'driver': 'SQL Server',
    'server': 'my_server',
    'database': 'my_database',
    'user': 'my_user',
    'password': 'my_password',
}

# Connect to the SQL Server database using pyodbc
conn_str = f"DRIVER={{{db_config['driver']}}};SERVER={db_config['server']};DATABASE={db_config['database']};UID={db_config['user']};PWD={db_config['password']};"
# print(pyodbc.drivers())
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

# Create the SQLAlchemy engine and session
engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str)}")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Create the SQLDatabase instance
db = SQLDatabase(session.connection())

# Create the agent executor
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db)
agent_executor = create_sql_agent(
    llm=OpenAI(temperature=0),
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True
)
```

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**What I Tried:**

I attempted to connect to a SQL Server using pyodbc in Python by providing the appropriate connection string. The connection string includes the host address, username, password, and database name.

Unfortunately, the connection attempt resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Chat GPT With SQL\test.py", line 23, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')
```

However I am able to connect with my database using below method

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)

# Create a cursor object to interact with the database
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

But I want to create a agent executor I am trying to use the pyodbc.

Comment: it sounds like the connection string is wrong. Do you have a server installed locally? Is 1433 the correct port it's running on?

Comment: No, it's my test store server. It's running on the default port. As i said I am able to connect via simple method which is 

conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)

# Create a cursor object to interact with the database
cursor = conn.cursor()

But unable to do it when I am trying using pyodbc

Comment: Mysql is not sql server though

Comment: Do I need to change the driver?

I am new to do this any suggestions on how can I make this work, already did some google search but was unable to find the same.

Comment: You can't use sql server driver to connect to a mysql server, it's a different system. Just look on how to use odbc and mysql

Comment: I tried what you suggested I installed the ODBC driver on my server and also checked the ODBC drivers there.

The command I used: `odbcinst -q -d`

I got the below results

[MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver]
[MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver]

Now I modified my connection string accordingly to below

`odbc_connection_string = f"DRIVER={{MySQL ODBC 8.0 UNICODE Driver}};SERVER={host},3306;DATABASE={database};USER={user};PASSWORD={password}"`

Now I got another error `'[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Comment: You have way too many {} around the driver property. Check Google on how to write correct connectionstrings for odbc + mysql